# How do you get on the same world?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to play minecraft with my cousin on the same world. We both have iPods and have no idea how to connect both of us to be on one of our worlds. How do you do it???

Answer (score 0):

Play in multiplayer. Using direct connection (opening a world to LAN and playing in it's local IP adress and port) or hosting a free server and playing in it with your cousin (joining to the server's adress).